# For dotnetcore 3.1 Windows service how to stop, uninstall, install and start the service with a powershell script 5.1

Tags: powershell, .net-core, azure-devops, windows-services, .net-core-3.1

## For starters i made the below script for PS 5.1 (i know that PS 6.0 has the Remove-Service option but not 5.1).

## I have all the required .exe, dll's and config's along with this script that is packaged as an artifact and will be deployed on the Headnode directory of the target.

## Not sure if the below script will uninstall and install the service. But i can see that it is deleting and starting the new service when i run it.**

````
```
$acl = Get-Acl "C:\Program Files\Matt\Wservice"
$aclRuleArgs = "XYZ", "Read,Write,ReadAndExecute", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($aclRuleArgs)
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
if (Get-Service "Wservice" -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue')
{
     Stop-Service -Name Wservice -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
     (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -filter "Name='Wservice'").delete()
     Write-Host "Please wait until removing the : Wservice  " 
     Start-Sleep -s 30 
    }
$Username = 'xyz'
$Password = '123'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
New-Service -Name  Wservice -BinaryPathName "C:\Program Files\Matt\Wservice\Wservice.exe" -Credential $MySecureCreds -DisplayName "WserviceService"  -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service -Name "Wservice"
```
````

Answer (score 0):

- Powershell core 6.0/7.0 dosent seem to have `get-wmiobject`, WMI is depreceated, then we have to use CIM using `Get-CIMInstance`.

Rest all seem OK. Coreected code:

```
$acl = Get-Acl "C:\Program Files\Matt\Wservice"
$aclRuleArgs = "XYZ", "Read,Write,ReadAndExecute", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($aclRuleArgs)
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
if (Get-Service "Wservice" -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue')
{
     Stop-Service -Name Wservice -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
     (Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_Service -filter "Name='Wservice'").delete()
     Write-Host "Please wait until removing the : Wservice  " 
     Start-Sleep -s 30 
    }
$Username = 'xyz'
$Password = '123'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
New-Service -Name  Wservice -BinaryPathName "C:\Program Files\Matt\Wservice\Wservice.exe" -Credential $MySecureCreds -DisplayName "WserviceService"  -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service -Name "Wservice"
```

Comment: Thanks @wasif Hasan for checking and correcting.
But i have a dependency to use PS 5.1 and not 6.0 or 7.0.
Also i have seen some code with the below runtime options for .netframework, not sure if there is something similar to use in .netcore3.1 runtime 

```$RunTimeDirectory = $([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory())
$InstallUtilPath = ("{0}{1}" -f $RunTimeDirectory,"InstallUtil.exe")```

Also if am properly doing the stop, uninstall then install and start cleanly without issues with the written script.

Comment: Just a point of note: As for this... [But i have a dependency to use PS 5.1], this does not matter as CIM is in v5x as well and it's best to get in the habit of using CIM vs WMI unless there is some that CIM is not giving you that WMI is not. Also, avoid putting code response in the comments, update your original post so that it can be followed and responded to more appropriately. Based on your ask though, you seem to be asking, [How do I replicate the PSCore Remove-Service cmdlets in PSv5x?]. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: [powershell 'remove a service'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+%27remove+a+service%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=63d5b10590b24698beb9044633b3ffcb&sp=-1&pq=powershell+%27remove+a+service%27&sc=3-29&qs=n&sk=&cvid=63d5b10590b24698beb9044633b3ffcb)

Comment: Please ignore my above comment as my code does the work and i wouldn't be needing further help. Thanks for checking @postanote